# How to get the rules from one dataframe and apply it to other dataframe to get the stats in python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, algorithm, numpy

I have two data frame df1 and df2 as shown

```
  type  follow  following  sum   count                      
0 i_12    hard    norm     250     1                    
1 i_45    norm    norm     450     2                    
2 k_2     ease    hard     345     5                    
3 i_8     hard    norm     56      1                    
4 j_9     ease    ease     5       5

    type   follow  following  sum   count
0  i_group  hard    norm       780   67
1  i_group  norm    norm       567   7
2  k_group  ease    hard       678   5
3  j_group  ease    ease       5     5
```

here, the column [follow & following] is rules and [sum & count] is stats for the same.
I want to write a code that will take rules from df2 and type for which the rules will apply on df1 and get the row from df1 which will satisfy it.

**for ex**
*[i_12, i_45, i_8] belongs to "i_group"*,  for which they have different stats for different rules.

So I just have to pass column[type, follow, following] from df2 and it should return the result from df1 as shown below.

```
 type   follow  following  sum   count
i_group hard     norm      306    2           #WHICH IS A SUM OF ROW 0 AND 3 
i_group norm     norm      56     1           #and so on.....
```

Comment: Looks like df1 and df2 have the same column names, you can try iterate over them by `for df in [df1,df2]:`

Comment: No, please don't iterate over the dfs, there is absolutely no reason to do so. Better try something like `df1.type.str.split('_').to_list()` to get the groups, then `groupby` etc.

Comment: iterating will take lot of time, it wouldn't be acceptable. @tianlinhe

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need first match `type` between both `DataFrame`s, then for filter columns by `df2` is used [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and last if necessary aggregate `sum`:

```
df = (df1.assign(type=df1['type'].replace('\d+', 'group', regex=True))
         .merge(df2[['type','follow','following']])
         .groupby(['type','follow','following'], as_index=False).sum())

print (df)
      type follow following  sum  count
0  i_group   hard      norm  306      2
1  i_group   norm      norm  450      2
2  j_group   ease      ease    5      5
3  k_group   ease      hard  345      5
```